# Dynamically populating Range with chained IF statements in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am automating a workbook that uses chained IF statements (non-VBA) across 4 worksheets to generate an output file for upload.

Here is a quick rundown of the code to give context:

1. Create new worksheet and populate first row from array (works)
2. Populate second row with IF formulas from array
3. Populate rest of table with dynamic IF functions used above (seems to work though rather rudimentary)

### [Updated Code below]

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range

TestFormulas() = Array("=If 'Sheet1'!P2 = 'Redundant' Then cell.Value = ''
ElseIf 'Sheet1'!P2 = 'Peripheral' Then cell.Value = '' Else cell.Value = 1")

    With WS
        For i = LBound(TestFormulas()) To UBound(TestFormulas())
          .Cells(2, 1 + i).Formula = TestFormulas(i)
        Next i
    End With

    Range("A3:BN74").Formula = "=A2"
```

The result I am looking to achieve is that the array fills all the rows across with the correct IF statements and then the Range completes the dynamic fill of the relevant cells.

Error I am receiving is

> '1004: Application-Defined or Object-Defined error'

and the line `.Cells(2, 1 + i).Formula = TestFormulas(i)` is highlighted yellow.

Comment: The "Formula" you are using is not a viable worksheet formula.  Worksheet formulas do not use IF/THEN/ELSE verbiage.

Comment: And `Range("A2:BN74").Formula = "=A2"` will fill those cells with a circular reference.

Comment: Have you written a working If formula directly in an Excel cell? If so, copy paste that formula into your code and adjust for the quotes.  If not, you will need to learn to write a working If formula.  What you have now, as @ScottCraner has already pointed out, is invalid.

Comment: @tigeravatar I copy/pasted it in and adjusted for the quotes to no avail before realizing the issue. I've updated the code and it fills, though not as a formula.

Here is an example of how the array looks now (using simple code to see if I can't get it to work):

Dim cell As Range
TestFormulas() = Array("If cell.Value <> 1 Then cell.Value = 2 Else cell.Value = 4")

Comment: @ScottCraner The If function now works outside of the array, though, for some reason, it does not function inside. Even setting the loop to .Cells(2, 1 + i).Formula = TestFormulas(i) results in a string being passed through to the respective cell.

Comment: No that still is not in a format acceptable to a worksheet formula.  `IF(,,)`  there is no THEN/ELSE in excel worksheet formulas.

Comment: Write the formula in the worksheet, get it working in the worksheet not vba code.  Then copy and paste that formula into vba.

Comment: @ScottCraner I was under the impression I would have to use the VBA code for the IF/THEN statement, rather than just filling it with the Excel If statement formula and doubling up on the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you've adjusted for quotes, but you have changed them to single quotes instead of leaving them as double quotes

The formula should be adjusted like this....

```
=If 'Sheet1'!P2 = ""Redundant"" Then ...
```

Note the doubling of the double quotes.

Also, the Excel spreadsheet does not understand vba code, so your formula should look something like this:

```
=IF('Sheet1'!P2 = ""Redundant"","""",IF(...
```